# Hertz-Millis theory and quantum criticality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, renormalization, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, fermi-liquids

Hartz-Millis(HM) theory is a model which exhibits quantum phase transition. The HM action following [Altland & Simons](https://books.google.com/books?id=GpF0Pgo8CqAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) is given by
$$
S = \frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{\omega_{n}}\int \frac{d^d q}{(2\pi)^d}\left(\delta+q^2+\frac{|\omega_n|}{\Gamma(q)}\right)|\phi|^2+ u\int dx d\tau\ u^4(x,\tau)
$$
Where $|\phi|^2 = \phi(q,\omega_{n})\phi(-q,\omega_{-n})$.

Following RG analysis one can find different regimes in the vicinity of the quantum critical point. Of which one particular regime is **quantum critical regime**. As mentioned by the authors that this region is bounded by the inequality $T \ll r^{z/2}$ and on the other hand if $T \gg r^{z/2}$ corresponds to Fermi liquid regime.

Where $z$ is the dynamical exponent and
$$
\delta(b) = b^2 r
$$

I understood the reasoning behind the derivation the quantum critical point yet how to derive
$T \ll r^{z/2}$ and $T \gg r^{z/2}$ regimes are not clear to me. Can anyone shade some light on this?